# Which simulator corresponds to 12.9 inch display in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to update my app in iTunesConnect, and apple keeps telling me I need a screenshot for 12.9 inch display. It seems like none of the simulators I have match the image dimensions they're asking for. I assume they want an iPad screenshot - am I missing it, or just doing something wrong? Here's what I have in xcode 7:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPad PRO is 12.9 inch with 264 ppi and a resolution of 2048 x 2732. You can add it in Xcode:

[image]

Comment: How do I get that simulator? I went to the list of downloadable simulators within xcode and there are no more updates.

Comment: In Xcode click on simulators > Add additional simulators > iPad Pro (12.9 inch) > Download

Comment: Hmm my xcode 7 doesn't seem to have a "simulators" menu as you're describing - is that in xcode8 ?

Comment: In the picture that you have added in that menu at the bottom. Check my post, added an image.

Comment: Huh yeah I don't have that option, mine just says "More simulators..." which brings me to a "downloads" dialog. Are you using xcode 8?